# Get all variable names in a class

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class and I want to find all of its *public fields* (not methods). How can I do this?

Comment: You should be able to do this using [Reflection API](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/).

Answer (score 153, accepted):

```
Field[] fields = YourClassName.class.getFields();
```

returns an array of all public variables of the class.

`getFields()` return the fields in the whole class-heirarcy. If you want to have the fields defined only in the class in question, and not its superclasses, use `getDeclaredFields()`, and filter the `public` ones with the following `Modifier` approach:

```
Modifier.isPublic(field.getModifiers());
```

The `YourClassName.class` literal actually represents an object of type [`java.lang.Class`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).  Check its docs for more interesting reflection methods.

The `Field` class above is [`java.lang.reflect.Field`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html). You may take a look at the whole [`java.lang.reflect`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html) package.

Comment: just a note - initially my answer contained a wrong statement, yet it was upvoted a number of times. Please read more carefully ;)

Comment: @downvoter - the mistake was before. If you see one now, please share.

Comment: is this solution slow ? or can we use it freely ?

Comment: it's ok. But don't overuse it.

Answer (score 56):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classMembers.html also has charts for locating methods and constructors.

[image]

Answer (score 20):

You can use any of the two based on your need:

```
Field[] fields = ClassName.class.getFields(); // returns inherited members but not private members.
Field[] fields = ClassName.class.getDeclaredFields(); // returns all members including private members but not inherited members.
```

To filter only the public fields from the above list (based on requirement) use below code:

```
List<Field> fieldList = Arrays.asList(fields).stream().filter(field -> Modifier.isPublic(field.getModifiers())).collect(
    Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by few users, below code can help find all the fields in a given class.

```
TestClass testObject= new TestClass().getClass();
Method[] methods = testObject.getMethods();
for (Method method:methods)
{
    String name=method.getName();
    if(name.startsWith("get"))
    {
        System.out.println(name.substring(3));
    }else if(name.startsWith("is"))
    {
        System.out.println(name.substring(2));
    }
}
```

However a more interesting approach is below:

With the help of Jackson library, I was able to find all class properties of type String/integer/double, and respective values in a Map class. (*without using reflections api!*)

```
TestClass testObject = new TestClass();
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper m = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();

Map<String,Object> props = m.convertValue(testObject, Map.class);

for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : props.entrySet()){
    if(entry.getValue() instanceof String || entry.getValue() instanceof Integer || entry.getValue() instanceof Double){
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "-->" + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't Jackson use reflection? Correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

List fields=Arrays.stream(reservation.class.getDeclaredFields()).map(Field::getName).toList();

It returns the list of all members declared inside a class including the private members.