# Read out all fields and their content of an object using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java: get all variable names in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126714/java-get-all-variable-names-in-a-class)

How can I read out all fields and their content of an `Object o` by using the reflection api.
I would begin with `o.getClass().getDeclaredFields()` but don't know how to continue.

Anyone got an idea ?

Comment: Maybe this may help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/index.html

Answer (score 5):

`o.getClass().getDeclaredFields()` will return an array of [`Field`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) instances. For each `Field` `f` in your array, you can access it's value with `f.get(o)`.

---

**Edit** Thank you to @MarkoTopolnik for pointing this out: if you plan to read non-public fields, be sure to first invoke `f.setAccessible(true)` before getting their values.

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow but so far this seems to be the answer i was looking for. Thanks !

Comment: One important tip, though: if you plan to read non-public fields, be sure to first invoke `f.setAccessible(true)` before getting its value. @A.R.S. if I may suggest, add this to your answer.