# Getting annotated variables from a class

Tags: java, reflection

This question is a follow up to a question I found before
[java: get all variable names in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126714/java-get-all-variable-names-in-a-class)

What I want is to get variables from a class, but instead of getting them all, I want only the variables that have the annotation `@isSearchable` .

So basically I have 2 questions :

- How do I create an annotation ?
- How to filter my fields by only this annotation ?

And one more thing , if it is something I'm using frequently is it advisable (I'm guessing reflections should be slow).

Thank you

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I wasn't familiar with Annotations or if this is a use case for them. 
Thank you all for your answers, this was really helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/** Annotation declaration */
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface isSearchable{
    //...   
}

@isSearchable
public String anyField = "any value";
```

checking like:

```
//use MyClass.class.getDeclaredFields() if you want the fields only for this class.
//.getFields() returns the fields for all the class hierarchy
for(Field field : MyClass.class.getFields()){
    isSearchable s = field.getAnnotation(isSearchable.class);
    if (s != null) {
        //field has the annotation isSearchable
    } else {
        //field has not the annotation
    }
}
```

Comment: Still one question, is it advisable to use it just to economize some code writing everytime ?

Comment: it depends, generally we should avoid reflection as it involves the overhead, but if much is gained in terms of maintanability/readability/testability, I think we can use it. and should rely on profilers to know the area for optimization if needed

Answer (score 2):

> How to filter my fields by only this annotation ?

You can get by this simple snippet

```
Field field = ... //obtain field object
Annotation[] annotations = field.getDeclaredAnnotations();

for(Annotation annotation : annotations){
    if(annotation instanceof IsSearchable){
        MyAnnotation myAnnotation = (MyAnnotation) annotation;
        System.out.println("name: " + myAnnotation.name());
        System.out.println("value: " + myAnnotation.value());
    }
}
```

In the above snippet you are basically filtering only `IsSearchable` annotations.

Regarding your `one more thing` query

Yes reflection will be slow as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435553/java-reflection-performance), if its possible to avoid, would advise you to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example

```
class Test {
    @IsSearchable
    String str1;
    String str2;

    @Target(ElementType.FIELD)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @interface IsSearchable {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for (Field f : Test.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (f.getAnnotation(IsSearchable.class) != null) {
                System.out.println(f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

prints

```
java.lang.String Test.str1
```

Answer (score 1):

[Field.getDeclaredAnnotations()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getDeclaredAnnotations%28%29) gives you the annotations for each field.

To answer your supplementary question, I would normally expect reflection to be slow. Having said that, I perhaps wouldn't worry about optimising until this becomes a problem for you.

Hint: Make sure you're checking the [up-to-date Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/). Google tends to give me Java 1.4 Javadocs, and annotations didn't exist prior to Java 5.