# Obtain HttpStatus ReasonPhrase text in Swagger message

Tags: java, swagger, http-status-codes, apache-httpcomponents

Using `org.apache.http` with

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
   <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
   <version>4.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

to depict the swagger configuration(not just the sole purpose of the library, though) on an endpoint as follows:

```
@ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(code = HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST, message = "Bad Request"),
    @ApiResponse(code = HttpStatus.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, message = "Server Error")
})
```

What I would want to do is replace the `"Bad Request"` with an equivalent Enumeration (supposedly) to avoid hardcoding the message every time.

***Q1*** - I tried looking out for one inside the `HTTP` package but couldn't find one. Is there any existing known Enum/Class for reason phrases to achieve this?

***Q2*** - The other way thought of is, I can get the variable name from the `HttpStatus.java` (since the variable name itself is good enough as a phrase). But the doubt again is [implementing reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126714/java-get-all-variable-names-in-a-class) could be costlier in terms of business logic for a reason phrase. So, in short, I am trying to focus on Q1 primarily for this.

***Note*** - Of course, owing to the fact, that I would not want to explicitly define a dependency just for the sake of fetching the reason phrases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was adding a class with static string bundles equivalent to [org.apache.HttpStatus](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpStatus.html) integer codes, something like -

```
public class SwaggerMessage {

    public static final String SC_OK = "OK";
    public static final String SC_CREATED = "Created";
    public static final String SC_ACCEPTED = "Accepted";
    public static final String SC_NO_CONTENT = "No Content";

    public static final String SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY = "Moved Permanently";

    public static final String BAD_REQUEST = "Bad Request";
    public static final String SC_UNAUTHORIZED = "Unauthorized";
    public static final String SC_FORBIDDEN = "Forbidden";
    public static final String SC_NOT_FOUND = "Not Found";

    public static final String SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR = "Server Error";
    public static final String SC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED = "Not Implemented";
    public static final String SC_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE = "Service Unavailable";

}
```

***Note*** - Seeking a cleaner solution still and the above is upto my need in the service implemented.

Comment: I tried to do a similar thing with the status codes and text reasons associated with Spring's HttpStatus enum, but since they are not constants they can't be used in a swagger annotation.