# Get all variable names in methods

Tags: java, javaparser

I would like to retrieve all variable names in all methods of a java file. Example Like a Person.java contains

```
class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    public static void main() {
            String test = "test";
            Person p1 = new Person();
            p1.setName("John");
    }
    public void setName(String name)   {
            this.firstName = name;
    }

}
```

i would like to be able to print out all variables declared. I have tried using javaparser to retrieve them.
However, i can only retrieve variables declared in the class which is

```
firstName

lastName
```

I want to be able to retrieve all variables declared in main method as well

```
firstName
lastName
test
```

My javaparser method is

```
public static void getVariables(String inputFilePath) {
    try {
        CompilationUnit cu = StaticJavaParser.parse(new File(inputFilePath));

        cu.findAll(FieldDeclaration.class).forEach(field -> {
            field.getVariables().forEach(variable -> {
                System.out.println(variable.getName());
                variable.getInitializer().ifPresent(initValue -> 
                System.out.println(initValue.toString()));
            });
        });
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
        System.out.println(fe.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Solved

As following Eugene's suggestion, i am able to retrieve all variables now

```
public static void getVariables(String inputFilePath) {
    try {
        CompilationUnit cu = StaticJavaParser.parse(new File(inputFilePath));
        cu.findAll(VariableDeclarator.class).forEach(variable -> {
            System.out.println(variable);
        });
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2126714/2987755 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/6817062/2987755

Comment: @ElliottFrisch im trying to learn obfuscation, i want to be able to change all the variable names to some random stuff

Comment: To find `test`, don't first have to `findAll(MethodDeclaration.class)` to find function `main()` and then look in the returned node for local variable definitions?

Comment: @DanielJunglas yeh i been thinking about, cant't  seem to make it work

Comment: I don't know `StaticJavaParser` at all, but I would think that once you have a `MethodDeclaration` you can use `getBody()` to get the actual definition. Then in that definition you can find any local variables?

Comment: hmm, didn't know about the getBody(), could give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `FieldDeclaration.class` into `CompilationUnit`'s findAll() method. So, as asked, it gets you all declared fields.

If you want to list all declared variables, use `VariableDeclarator.class` from the same package – it will get you all of those, including the ones declared as fields.