# How to check all parts of an Object in Java in a loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, object

I'm wondering if there is an efficient way to check all the parts of a Java object at once without calling on each one. So let's say I have this example:

`Example(boolean part1, int part2, boolean part3)`

and I created this Example object:

`Example(true, 6, false)`

I plan on making a String array that would hold all these values that would look like:

`"true", "6", "false"`

Would it be possible to make a loop that would grab each part of this object?

Comment: Is `Example(...)` a constructor call?

Comment: So you essentially want to iterate over class fields? I don't think this is possible without reflection, i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126714/java-get-all-variable-names-in-a-class

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Reflection` get the fields of the class and loop over the fields array and call `setAccessible(true)` to allow access if the field is private and get its value

```
 static class Example {

        private boolean part1;
        private int part2;
        private boolean part3;

        public Example(boolean part1, int part2, boolean part3) {
            this.part1 = part1;
            this.part2 = part2;
            this.part3 = part3;
        }
    }
```

, main

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example example = new Example(true, 1, false);
        Field[] fields = example.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Field f : fields) {
            f.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                list.add(String.valueOf(f.get(example)));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        String[] strings = list.toArray(new String[0]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));
    }
```

, output

```
[true, 1, false]
```

More information: [Reflection Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/index.html)